# TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur withing 60 seconds

Tags: networking, routing, openvpn, isp, tls

I'm working remotely using my laptop by connecting to the office VPN server (in India), if I connect from UAE, the connection works immediately fine... But now when I try to connect from Egypt (using the same laptop and setup), the connection keeps failing until it accidentally works after retrying the connection for 10s of times.

When it fails, I receive the error: TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur withing 60 seconds

when I tried "traceroute ", I noticed that the connection routes in stupid way far from destination and dies somewhere around France!! (although the route from Egypt to India was not expected to route through west of Europe!)

Calling the ISP support (of course) didn't help, they just don't understand sh*t about something like this, but they confirmed that they are not blocking any connections!

Any idea about what could be the reason?
Is there a way I can force the route table to the destination instead of relying on the automatic routing?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Maybe the ISP in India cheaped out. Or maybe the ISP in Egypt. Really no way to tell. // Sounds like extreme packet loss to me. 60 seconds should be plenty.

Comment: Which DNS server are you using? Is it the one supplied automatically by the Egyptian ISP? Do you know that the IP address is correct?